# Regular expression with if condition

Tags: regex

I am new to regular expression. I am trying to construct a regular expression that
first three characters must be alphabets and then the rest of the string could be any character. If the part of the string after first three characters contains & then this part should start and end with `"`.

I was able to construct `^[a-z]{3}`, but stuck at conditional statement.

For example `abcENT` and `abc"E&T"` are valid strings but not `abcE&T`.

Can this be done in a single expression?

Comment: You could do this with alternation. Something like `^[a-z]{3}([^&]*|".*")$`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In most regex flavors, you may use simple lookaheads to make sure some text is present or not somewhere to the right of the current locations, and using an alternation operator `|` it possible to check for alternatives.

So, we basically have 2 alternatives: there is a `&` somewhere in the string after the first 3 alphabets, or not. Thus, we can use

```
^[A-Za-z]{3}(?:(?=.*&)".*"|(?!.*&).*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dS1dG4/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Za-z]{3}` - 3 alphabets
- `(?:(?=.*&)".*"|(?!.*&).*)` - Either of the two alternatives:

  - `(?=.*&)".*"` - if there is a `&` somewhere in the string (`(?=.*&)`) match `"`, then any 0+ characters, and then `"`
  - `|` - or
  - `(?!.*&).*` - if there is no `&` (`(?!.*&)`) in the string, just match any 0+ chars up to the...
- `$` - end of string.

In PCRE, or .NET, or some other regex flavors, you have access to the *conditional construct*. Here is a [PCRE demo](https://regex101.com/r/dS1dG4/2):

```
^[A-Za-z]{3}(?(?=.*&)".*"|.*)$
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?(?=.*&)".*"|.*)` means:

- `(?(?=.*&)` - if there is a `&` after any 0+ characters...
- `".*"` - match `"anything here"`-like strings
- `|` - or, if there is no `&`
- `.*`  - match any 0+ chars from the current position (i.e. after the first 3 alphabets).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your great explanation. Could you please make some regex for me? it is,<a Anystring1 href="Anystring2?Anystring3"Anystring4>, here I'd like to get Anystring2 and Anystring3. And also please note that question mark, it may exist or not. like this. Anystring<a Anystring1 href="Anystring2"Anystring4>Anystring, So here Anystring3 is empty.  I made this regex, but it works only when there is question mark. and not works as I expected when no question mark in the sentence. Regards.

Comment: @Lin See [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Besides, if you have a question, you should ask it, the comments are only to clarify things for the actual issue stated in OP.

Comment: I know it, but this site restricted me for asking question. not sure about the reason. Hope your warm help for my issue.

Answer (score 3):

A conditional statement could be use with | and groups, but it probably will be complicated.

```
^[a-z]{3}([^&]*$|".*"$)
```

You might think about using plain old string manipulation for this task, it probably will be simple

Answer (score 2):

Yeah this is possible, it is not really an if, but in your case you can make an "or" with regex capturing Group. Your regex would look something like that:

```
\d{3}(\".*\"|[^&]*)
```

P.S. here is a good site to test and learn These things:
https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

The expression itself will depend on the regexp parser you'll use. If you're using Python, shell, vim, boost, etc. , the same symbol could have different meanings.

I would try the following :

```
$ echo 'abc"&def"' | grep -E "^[a-zA-Z]{3}(\".*\&.*\"|[^&]*)"
abc"&def"
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions don't necessarily support conditionals as in 'if', to achive this in a general case you have to state your conditions as alternatives. (But see Wiktor's comment, depending on your regex engine there might be conditionals available.)

For a relatively basic solution you might try something like this:

```
^[a-z]{3}([^&]*|\..*\.)$
```

Which says "After four letters, there should be a string of any length with no ampersand (&) OR a string starting and ending with a full stop (.).

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36xybswe(v=vs.110).aspx#Conditional_Expr

Comment: Wiktor: Interesting extension. Worth a look if your regex engine supports it.

Comment: After three letters there should be a string of any length , but this works even with no string after three letters. Please could you help ?

Comment: A string of any length does not include a string of length 0?