# How to capture string using regex

Tags: regex

My current regex query is

```
    (?P<TestName>(?<=_)[^\s]+)
```

Its able to capture "ABCD" and "Adjust_Path". I would like to capture the string "LED" as well from  the list below

```
    4039_ABCD
    LED
    2020_Adjust_Path
```

Comment: With the samples shown, maybe `^(?:\d+_)?(?P<TestName>\w+)` will do

Comment: in which language you are doing regex query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might assert an underscore to the left, and match any char except a whitespace char or underscore till the end of the string.

```
(?P<TestName>(?<=_)\S+|[^\s_]+)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?P<TestName>` Named group `TestName`

  - `(?<=_)` Positive lookbehind, assert `_` directly to the left
  - `\S+` Match 1+ times a non whitespace char
  - `|` Or
  - `[^\s_]+` Match 1+ times any char except `_` or a whitespace char
- `)` Close group `TestName`
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VbxMpO/1).

If there has to be a digit present before the underscore:

```
(?P<TestName>(?<=\d_)\S+|[^\s_]+)$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=_)[^\s]+)|((?!.*_)[^\s]+)
```

|       : for the 2 cases (alternatives)

(?!.*_) : second case : not every string with a _

More info

[Regular expression with if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222950/regular-expression-with-if-condition)